# What does lxc-container-default-with-nesting AppArmor profile do?

Tags: lxc, apparmor

I'm using nested LXC with lxc-container-default-with-nesting profile which looks like the following.

```
profile lxc-container-default-with-nesting flags=(attach_disconnected,mediate_deleted) {
  #include <abstractions/lxc/container-base>
  #include <abstractions/lxc/start-container>

#  Uncomment the line below if you are not using cgmanager
#  mount fstype=cgroup -> /sys/fs/cgroup/**,

  deny /dev/.lxc/proc/** rw,
  deny /dev/.lxc/sys/** rw,
  mount fstype=proc -> /var/cache/lxc/**,
  mount fstype=sysfs -> /var/cache/lxc/**,
  mount options=(rw,bind),
}
```

and I have two questions about the following line.

```
  mount fstype=proc -> /var/cache/lxc/**,
```

1. Why is it safe to allow container to mount /proc ?
2. Why container needs to mount /proc under /var/cache/lxc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Nested Container Configuration

That config file allows you to create **nested** LXC containers, one inside another. By default, this is disabled since it bypasses some of the default cgroup restrictions ([more info here](https://www.stgraber.org/2013/12/21/lxc-1-0-advanced-container-usage/)).

In general, it changes apparmor rules to allow lxc to re-mount certain system resources (with certain restrictions) inside the container.

### lxc.container.conf

If you look at `man lxc.container.conf`, this section explains settings you can edit for how `proc` is mounted. I **think** it uses `proc:mixed` by default **(but I haven't confirmed this!)**

```
  lxc.mount.auto
          specify which standard kernel file systems should be
          automatically mounted. This may dramatically simplify
          the configuration. The file systems are:

          · proc:mixed (or proc):
            mount /proc as read-write, but
            remount /proc/sys and
            /proc/sysrq-trigger read-only
            for security / container isolation purposes.

          · proc:rw: mount
            /proc as read-write
```

## Unprivileged LXC

As an aside, if you're not using unprivileged LXC, you should be. **Seriously**. It adds an additional layer of protection that restricts what the `root` user in the container can do (It actually maps it to a non-root user outside the container). This provides an additional layer of protection for `/proc` in case something slips by the apparmour rules.

As far as why it uses `/var/cache/lxc`, I have no idea. A guess would be that it has to do with not conflicting with `cgmanager`. Looking at the source might be a good place to start if you're interested in the reasoning.